# Call fastlane function from Ruby file

Tags: ruby, macos, fastlane

This is quite a simple question. I need to call a fastlane lane from an external Ruby file. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, however make sure you're not using private API.

```
require 'fastlane'
Fastlane::Runner.new.execute("beta")
```